# Animation not showing after restarting Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

I'll do my best to explain my issue without a video

I have a login activity where upon successful login, the EditText and Button fields fade out and a "logging in" TextView fades in (using Facebook Shimmer). This works great!! However, upon successfully login we are greeted by a blank activity (still fine). Now, I overwrote the back button so that when the back button is pressed, the user is forced to login again. My problem arises with the user hits the login button at this time. The Edit Text and Button elements fade out nicely but the "logging in" TextView never fades in.

Below are some picture examples.  I will also post the source code for LoginActivity.class and if you want to download the project it is available at: `git@github.com:fbgrecojr/Android-Application-Login-Activity-Template.git`

If you download the project, username: testuser and password: testpass will work.

Images:

1. Initial Login (working)
   [image]

[image]

2. Login Attempt after pressing the back button and then logging in again (which I overwrote to restart the intent)

[image]

LoginActivity.class

```
package com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.UI;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.HTTPManager.HttpManager;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.HTTPManager.RequestPackage;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.Parser.JSONParser;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.R;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.Session.Session;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.Structures.User;
import com.projects.fbgrecojr.logintemplate.Utility.UTILITY;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText userName, password;
    private Button login;
    private RelativeLayout image;
    private LinearLayout button, belowPic;
    private Animation fadeInImage, fadeInButton, bottomUp, fadeOut;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName,inputLayoutPassword;
    private ViewGroup hiddenPanel;
    private ShimmerFrameLayout container, loggingIn;
    private static final int SECOND = 1000;
    private static final int HALF_SECOND = 500;
    private static final int QUARTER_SECOND = 250;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //INITIALIZE ANIMATION ITEMS
        fadeInImage = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeInButton = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
        bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bottom_up_animation);
        fadeInImage.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
        bottomUp.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        //GET UI ELEMENTS
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        image = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.image);
        button = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button);
        container = (ShimmerFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.shimmer);
        belowPic = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.below_picture);
        loggingIn = (com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_shimmer);
        hiddenPanel = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.input);
        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_username);
        inputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.text_input_password);

        //SET UI PROPERTIES
        loggingIn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        userName.setCursorVisible(false);
        password.setCursorVisible(false);
        password.setHint("Password");
        userName.setHint("Username");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                userName.setCursorVisible(true);
                password.setCursorVisible(true);
                userName.requestFocus();
            }
        }, LoginActivity.SECOND * 3);

        //ANIMATIONS
        fadeInImage.setDuration(SECOND * 3);
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(SECOND);
        fadeOut.setDuration(SECOND);
        image.setAnimation(fadeInImage);
        fadeInButton.setStartOffset(SECOND + HALF_SECOND + QUARTER_SECOND);
        fadeInButton.setDuration(SECOND * 2);
        button.setAnimation(fadeInButton);
        hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        container.setDuration(SECOND * 2 + QUARTER_SECOND);
        container.setRepeatDelay(QUARTER_SECOND);
        container.setIntensity((float) 0.15);
        container.setBaseAlpha((float) 0.75);
        container.setFadingEdgeLength(3);
        container.setDropoff((float) 0.40);
        container.startShimmerAnimation();

        //ON CLICK LISTENERS
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:

                if(getUserName().getText().toString().equals("") || getUserName().getText().toString().equals(" ")) {
                    inputLayoutName.setError("enter username");
                }else if(getPassword().getText().toString().equals("") || getPassword().getText().toString().equals(" ")){
                    inputLayoutPassword.setError("enter password");
                }else{
                    //webservice
                    if (UTILITY.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                        RequestPackage p = new RequestPackage();
                        p.setMethod("GET");
                        p.setUri(UTILITY.UBUNTU_SERVER_URL);
                        p.setParam("query", "user");
                        p.setParam("username", getUserName().getText().toString());
                        new WebserviceCallOne().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, p);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you are not connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void animateExit() {
        //fade out annimation
        belowPic.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        belowPic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fadeInImage.setStartOffset(SECOND * 2);
        fadeInImage.setDuration(HALF_SECOND);
        loggingIn.startAnimation(fadeInImage);
        loggingIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loggingIn.setDuration(SECOND);
        loggingIn.startShimmerAnimation();
    }

    public EditText getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public EditText getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    private class WebserviceCallOne extends AsyncTask<RequestPackage, String, User> {
        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(RequestPackage... params) {
            String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
            return JSONParser.parseUserFeed(content);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User s) {
            Session.setCurrentUser(s);
            //if null, error stacktrace will print to the log. This is expected!!
            if(Session.getCurrentUser() == null){ //username was incorrect
                inputLayoutName.setError("username does not exist");
            }else{ //check password
                if(getPassword().getText().toString().equals(s.getPassword())){ //passwords match
                    animateExit();
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    },LoginActivity.SECOND * 4);
                }else{
                    inputLayoutPassword.setError("password incorrect");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity
     * as appropriate.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call    animateExit(); code in onResume methord

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      animateExit();
    }
```

Comment: I will try this, however when I was debugging, the onCreate method is executed.

Comment: in the animateExit() method. It is called upon successful login.  Reference the onPostExecute() method of the private class WebServiceCallOne

Comment: Also, putting the code in onResume did not solve the issue and I expected because I overwrote and put toast calls in the android lifecycle methods and onCreate() and onResume() are always being called in both the initial instance and the instance generated upon clicking the back button

Comment: @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      animateExit();
    }

Comment: because you are not clicking  WebserviceCall on after clicking on backbutton

Comment: your answer will not work. If you look at what happens in the animateExit() method, you will see that this can only be executed upon a successful login

Comment: Also, animateExit() IS being called every time that is not this issue. The EditText and Button elements fade out in the animateExit() method and this successfully happens when the submit button is pressed after going back to the login screen

Comment: also, if you examine the code, WebserviceCall is being executing each time the submit button is pressed (if it passes input validation) so I am "clicking WebserviceCall on after clicking on backbutton"

Answer (score 0):

1. override onResume() in your Activity.

   try starting your animation in onresume.
2. override onPause() in your Activity

   try stopping your animation in onPause.

Hope this Helps :)